# Include built ReactJS 16.x app into AngularJS 1.x

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

For a project I am working on, there is a situation where I have to include and `ReactJS` app which is already compiled into an `AngluarJS` project. `Chrome/Firefox` Browser is the `Enduser-Interface`.
I know that this setup isn't the best, unfortunately I have to deal with both frameworks in this exact setup.
**I am not allowed to use an `IFrame` neither.**

I googled a lot, searching for wrapper, which exists but only if the react project isn't already built.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: How do you intend to use the frameworks? Is the goal to slowly replace the AngularJS code with React?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is no long time goal in replacing. It is an integration between two systems / technologies.There will be always the main system using AngularJS, which includes the subsystem ReactJS as a compiled / built version.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure your requirement, as per my understanding, you can import the "ngmodule" to react component and render the angular script. In this case you can achieve it from server side rendering.

In our project, we have the common login module developed in Angular 1.x, we are rendering the angular module in React.

Comment: It is quite the opposite. First as stated I want to inlude / import an React app into an Angular ngmodule. Secondly the React component is already rendered / built, so we are not dealing with components / ngmodules, but with the output.